# Can I still publish an ios6 app to the apple store

Tags: ios, ios6, app-store

We have spent the last several months developing an app for iOS 6. I recognize that we need to update it for iOS 7 asap. However, can we still publish the iOS 6 app to the store?

We have never gone through the app store process before and want to start on it even though we will be replacing it soon with ios7 app.

Does the store just reject any new iOS6 APPS OR can we still publish it?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 is not universally available for all iOS devices.  Early generations of iPhones, iPods, and iPads are not compatible with the iOS 7 upgrade, yet they still have apps available in the App Store.  Plus iOS 7 was just released.  iOS 7 is new, therefore iOS 6 is still not obsolete.